# Implementing schematron rules

Tags: schematron

I am new with schematron and I have the following problem. This is the snippet from xhtml file:

```xhtml
<div class="provision">
  <!-- provision (SECTION) -->
  <header>
    <!-- headers -->
    <div class="desig">
      <!-- if provision then header/div@class=desig/span@class=num required -->
      <span class="num">1.</span>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">prov-title</h1>
  </header>
  <p class="prov">para-prov-level</p>
  <p class="prov">para-prov-level</p>
  <div class="glossary">
    <!-- glossary -->
    <!-- glossary requires dl -->
    <dl>
      <!-- dl should have dt, and at least one dd -->
      <dt> term </dt>
      <dd>definition</dd>
      <dt> term </dt>
      <dd>definition</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div class="level-1-grp">
    <!-- SUBSECTION -->
    <header>
      <div class="desig">
        <span class="num">(1)</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <p class="level-1">para-level-1</p>
    <div class="level-2-grp">
      <header>
        <div class="desig">
          <span class="num">(a)</span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <p class="level-2">para-level-2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="level-2-grp">
      <header>
        <div class="desig">
          <span class="num">(b)</span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <p class="level-2">para-level-2</p>
    </div>
    <p class="level-1">para-level-1</p>
  </div>
  <p class="prov">para-prov-level</p>
</div>
```

and I would like to create a rule to check 
if there is a `provision` then `header/div@class=desig/span@class=num` required and  `glossary` requires `dl`. I have been trying like this but it does not work:

```
<iso:pattern id="structure-provision">
  <iso:title>Testing for Provision structure...</iso:title>
  <iso:rule context="*:div[@class='provision']">
    <iso:assert test="self::*:header/div[@class ='desig']/*:span[@class='num']">if provision then header/div@class=desig/span@class=num required</iso:assert>
  </iso:rule>
</iso:pattern>

<!--glossory structure -->

<iso:pattern id="structure-glossory">
  <iso:title>Testing for Provision structure...</iso:title>
  <iso:rule context="*:div[@class='glossory']">
    <iso:assert test="self::*:dl">glossary requires dl</iso:assert>
    <iso:assert test="self::*:dl/dt">dl should have a dt</iso:assert>
  </iso:rule>

</iso:pattern>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which bit isn't working? All of it? Given your context nodes are correct, test node should be relative to that. When doing schematron, I always start simple. So for instance I force the asserts to prove the contexts, and change the document I'm validating to cut down on potential ambiguity. Unless you have some very clever tooling it's a massive pain to debug.

Answer (score 3):

You were missing a namespace on the div element in your first iso:assert.

The English language is not very precise, so I interpreted your requirements in 2 ways.

1) if there is a provision then (header/div@class=desig/span@class=num required AND glossary requires dl). "If X, then A and B". If this is the case, then only a single pattern should be used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">
    <sch:pattern id="structure-provision">
        <sch:title>Provisioning structure</sch:title>
        <sch:rule context="*:div[@class='provision']">
            <sch:assert test="*:header/*:div[@class ='desig']/*:span[@class='num']">
                The provision structure requires header/div@class=desig/span@class=num
            </sch:assert>
            <sch:assert test="*:div[@class='glossary']/*:dl">
                Glossary requires dl
            </sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

2) (if there is a provision then header/div@class=desig/span@class=num required) AND (glossary requires dl). "If X, then A. Also, if Y, then B." If this is the case, then two patterns should be used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">
    <sch:pattern id="provision-structure">
        <sch:title>Provisioning structure</sch:title>
        <sch:rule context="*:div[@class='provision']">
            <sch:assert test="*:header/*:div[@class ='desig']/*:span[@class='num']">
                The provision structure requires header/div@class=desig/span@class=num
            </sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>

    <sch:pattern id="glossary-structure">
        <sch:title>Provisioning structure</sch:title>
        <sch:rule context="*:div[@class='glossary']">
            <sch:assert test="*:dl">
                Glossary requires dl
            </sch:assert>
            <sch:assert test="*:dl/*:dt">
                dl requires dt
            </sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

I would recommend splitting your requirements up into several rules/patterns to make things more robust and organized. For example, have all of your rules related to provisioning structure within a single pattern. If glossary rules should be enforced regardless of whether the glossary is within a provisioning structure, then glossary should have its own pattern.

Also, I would define and use a namespace for the elements and use that within the schematron rules. I assume it is xhtml or similar? The xpath expressions would become something like:

```
<sch:rule context="xhtml:div[@class='provision']">
    <sch:assert test="xhtml:header/xhtml:div[@class ='desig']/xhtml:span[@class='num']">
        Rule text here
    </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```